# How to use multiple parameters in a ZF1 Route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-route

i was trying to add new routes to my Zend Framework 1 application. But it seems to understand my 2 params as one. How can i fix that?

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':name-:type', array('controller' => 'tour', 'action' => 'index'));
$route = $routeLang->chain($route);
$router->addRoute('tour', $route);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question again so others can get it quickly:

How to pass 'name' and 'type' parameters all together connected by dash ('-'), so if going to url: 'tour/index/**sampleName-sampleType**', Zend can recognize name is 'sampleName', type is 'sampleType'?

You need: Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex()

If you want url to match: 'www.example.com/sampleName-sampleType'

```
protected function _initRoutes ()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('(.+)-(.+)', array('controller' => 'tour', 'action' => 'index'), array(1 => 'name', 2=>'type'), '%s-%s');
    $router->addRoute('tour', $route);
}
```

Or if you want to match: 'www.example.com/sampleName-tour-sampleType'

```
protected function _initRoutes ()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();
    
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('(.+)-tour-(.+)', array('controller' => 'tour', 'action' => 'index'), array(1 => 'name', 2=>'type'), '%s-tour-%s');
    $router->addRoute('tour', $route);
}
```

Print it out in controller 'tour', action 'index':

```
echo '<br>Name is: ' . $this->getParam('name') . '<br>Type is: ' . $this->getParam('type');
```

Then go to url: '/tour/sampleName-sampleType', you will see the result:

> Name is: sampleName
>
> Type is: sampleType

**A little sugar:**

Actually your route is correctly set, however by default the routing pattern is: '/tour/index/name/sampleName/type/sampleType', your dash ('-') only worked as a separator for parameters, as in Zend does not recognize it as a connection string.

The following code is the complete code to add such a route to your Zend project for those who might need it.

**In Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initRoutes ()
{    
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $router = $front->getRouter();

    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':name/:type', array('controller' => 'tour', 'action' => 'index'));
    $router->addRoute('tour', $route);
}
```

Print it out in controller:

```
echo '<br>Name is: ' . $this->getParam('name') . '<br>Type is: ' . $this->getParam('type');
```

Comment: My Code throws an error once i call $this->url(array('name' => 'bla', 'type' => 123), 'tour');
It seems you cannot use dashes in a route.

Comment: I see the problem here, sorry I need to be clear with your question first, correct me if I were wrong. Do you want to add a dash in between your 'name' and 'type' and send them both together as one parameter? As in after going to: tour/index/firstString-secondString, you want Zend to recognize name is "firstString", type is "secondString"?

Comment: ye, i want the final url to be www.example.com/adventure-tour-1234
and i want adventure-tour as one and 1234 as another parameter

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hopefully it will solve your problem :)